# Core doesn't update with Composer

Tags: 8, drush, updating, composer

We use commands:

```
composer outdated drupal/*
drupal/core 8.6.10 8.6.13 Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.
```

It does show 8.6.13.

We run either `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies` or `composer update drupal/core:8.6.13 webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies` and we get nothing, it does update some dependencies and that is it. Our site is built with composer.

Here's the rest of the log:

```
composer update drupal/core:8.6.13 webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
Package "drupal/core:8.6.13" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Dependency "drupal/core" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Dependency "twig/twig" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 5 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating symfony/css-selector (v3.4.22 => v3.4.23): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/phpunit-bridge (v3.4.22 => v3.4.23): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/dom-crawler (v3.4.22 => v3.4.23): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/browser-kit (v4.2.3 => v4.2.4): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating squizlabs/php_codesniffer (3.4.0 => 3.4.1): Downloading (100%)
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles
root@dev /var/www/example.com # composer update drupal/core
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles
root@dev /var/www/example.com # drush status
 Drupal version   : 8.6.10
 Site URI         : default
 DB driver        : mysql
 DB hostname      : localhost
 DB port          : 3306
 DB username      : root
 DB name          : example
 Database         : Connected
 Drupal bootstrap : Successful
 Default theme    : seven
 Admin theme      : seven
 PHP binary       : /usr/bin/php7.2
 PHP config       : /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS           : Linux
 Drush script     : /usr/local/bin/drush
 Drush version    : 9.4.0
 Drush temp       : /tmp
 Drush configs    : /var/www/example.com/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
                    /var/www/example.com/drush/drush.yml
 Install profile  : standard
 Drupal root      : /var/www/example.com/web
 Site path        : sites/default
 Files, Public    : sites/default/files
 Files, Temp      : /tmp
```

Drush is still reporting 8.6.10

First time we did get the WSOD from https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3039408 so we ran `composer require twig/twig:1.37.1` to fix it.

Comment: Might be that you connected to a repo site that did not have 13 on it yet.  It was just released.  Try again later. FYI - Just updated my site with composer require drupal/core --update-with-dependencies and had no problems other than slow core download.

Comment: @CGMonroe  It doesn't update to 12 either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after we ran regular update (current version was 8.6.10), our website crashed. We followed this fix to recover from WSOD https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3039408#comment-13018093

After website was restored we tried running all kinds of composer commands to update (like mentioned in question) and it would just spit out "Nothing to install or update".

Solution:

1. remove `"twig/twig": "1.37.1",` from `composer.json`
2. Run again `composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies`

`Updating twig/twig (v1.37.1 => v1.38.2): Loading from cache
Updating drupal/core (8.6.10 => 8.6.13): Downloading (100%)`

So, not sure what's going on.

Comment: A bug arose in Drupal 8.6.10 when Twig updated to 1.38; the fix was to `require twig/twig:1.37.1` explicitly. That's most likely why you had `twig/twig` in your composer.json, when you normally wouldn't

Comment: @Clive yes, but why are the core updates locked to certain twig version? Having that twig line prevented from updating the website.

Comment: Perhaps the fix for Drupal's integration into 1.38 wasn't backwards compatible with its integration into 1.37? I haven't checked the code to be honest. I doubt they would've done it arbitrarily though, there'll be a good reason

Comment: I think they locked it because of a breaking change that shouldn’t have gone in upstream.

Comment: Wouldn't `composer why-not drupal/core:8.6.13` revealed the problem with Twig? People tend to forget that you can ask Composer why it is (not) doing stuff.

Answer (score -1):

We came across the similar issue while upgrading from 8.6.10 to 8.6.13, try deleting the core and then run

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

It should upgrade it to 8.6.13